# Split polygon using turf js and Leaflet draw

Tags: split, leaflet, polygon

I have a web map which uses Leaflet and turf js for geoprocessing, so I want to split a polygon using a line. Is there any way to do that? I want to split the polygon in to two just by one line

Comment: What kind of line? An infinite line on an infinite plane? A great circle on a geodesic surface? A 2-vertex `LineString`? What if one of the vertices falls withing the polygon?

Comment: A 2-vertex lineString, I want to split a parcel by line string